# Auto-refresh div using jQuery doesn't auto-refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me to function this?
The "call.php" page loads the "table__data.php" on "content_div" div, but it doesn't automatically refreshes the div in 3 seconds. I'm creating a page where it can display queue tickets being served.

Here's my code for table_data.php

```html
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" > -->
<table class="table  table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
<tr style="text-align: center;">
  <th style="width: 30%; background-color: black;" align="center"><strong style="font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; color: white; font-family:verdana; ">Ticket Number</strong></th>
  <th style="width: 30%; background-color: black;" align="center"><strong style="font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; color: white; font-family:verdana; ">Counter</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME','dswd_qms');

$link=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if($link===false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect.". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT a.ticket_id, a.ticket_no, a.proceed_to
                FROM qms_tickets AS a
                WHERE a.ticket_date = CURDATE() AND a.ticket_status = 2 OR a.ticket_status = 4 AND enabled = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr style='text-align: center;'><td style='font-size: 97px; font-weight: bold; color: red; font-family:verdana;'>#".$row["ticket_no"]."</td><td style='font-size: 97px; font-weight: bold; color: red; font-family:verdana;'>".$row["proceed_to"]."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
else{
  echo "0 Results";
}
?>
```

And here's my code for call.php

```html
<div id="counter_div" >
                                    <!-- <?php include_once'table_data.php'; ?> -->
                                </div> 
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    setInterval(function(){
                                        $('#counter_div').load('table_data.php');
                                    },3000);
                                });
                            </script>
```

Comment: Hey, there, did you tried return just for debugging in your table_data.php file anything like a `echo "hello world";` and see if you are loading that into your div? Could be just an `500 error` which means mostly syntax error in your php code and that's why you're not recieving anything

Comment: Other thing i released  is that with that javascript code you're gonna get just once time fill that div, and as i could read, you're expecting fill it each 3 seconds and for that, i'd recommend you use `setTimeOut` and `setInterval` functions

Comment: Hi @FernandoUrban i editted my code and add setInterval function to it but still no luck. I also tried to add echo to debug in my data table in table_data.php and yes, it loads on my div.

Comment: `<!-- <?php include_once'table_data.php'; ?> -->` – you know this is _not_ commenting out the PHP code, but that it will still be run, right? And your logic for the `0 Results` output is also bogus - you have already output the opening `table` tag and the `tr` with the header cells, and now you are just going to end it with `0 Results`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you tried is not right. Try this one,

```
// $(document).ready(function(){}); is when the document is ready or loads first time
$(document).ready(function(){});

// For loading page in certain intervals
setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#counter_div').load(' #counter_div');
}, 3 * 1000); // 3 * 1000 == 3 seconds
```

Comment: Are you trying to load content in the same page where you are firing setInterval?

Comment: No, I tried to load the content of 'table_data.php' on 'call.php'. It loads but doesn't refresh every 3seconds.

Comment: The content loads on the #counter_div of call.php, right?

Comment: Yes it loads on call.php

Comment: Have you tried loading the #counter_div itself ? See the edited code...

Comment: Did you used a space in .load(' #counter_div'); if not put one like I have.

Comment: Did you used a space in .load(' #counter_div'); if not put one like I have.

Comment: Did you used a space in .load(' #counter_div'); if not put one like I have.

Comment: Try putting the function outside the '$(document).ready(function(){});